# YiiStrap: TbModal Widget how use html inside the content spot

Tags: php, yii, widget, yii-extensions, simplemodal

My html is not working inside the 'content' => ' HTML CODE HERE  ' if i input text it is displaying as it should.

anyone knows how to get this to work?

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
         'id' => 'myModal',
          'content' => '
        div id="login-container">
        <div id="gravatar-border"></div>
        <img id="gravatar" class="profile-img" src="http://dev.yepster.com/img/defaultavatar.png">
        <div class="account-wall"></div>
       </div>', 
      'footer' => array(
```

Comment: Not working how? Missing `<` at the start of your div also

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'myModal')); ?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h4>Your title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="login-container">
         <div id="gravatar-border"></div>
         <img id="gravatar" class="profile-img" src="http://dev.yepster.com/img/defaultavatar.png">
         <div class="account-wall"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Close',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```